# Monitor weirdness/flickering with new Vaio PCG-3112L

Tags: display, graphics-card, sony-vaio

I have a Sony VAIO PCG-3112L running Windows 7. It worked fine on one monitor, but now I'm using it with a 2 year old LG Flatron W2252TQ-TF. The colors are sorta off (although that might just be the monitor), but more annoyingly there are many horizontal flickering lines. It's more noticeable on non-white backgrounds.

I tried rebooting the monitor, and reseting it to factory settings, but that didn't solve the issue.

What could be the cause of this? The monitor works fine with an Asus netbook. I have checked that both ends of the VGA cable are plugged in between the Vaio and the monitor.

**Update**: I tried with a Sceptre TV, and experienced the same issue. (The Asus with the same cable was fine for that TV.)

**Update 2**: Sometimes, using the same configuration described above with the LG monitor, the problem does not occur. I am not sure what causes this.

Comment: You might have discovered it by now but the VGA port of Vaio's is crappy. I have a Vaio VPCCW and when I use the VGA port to connect a monitor its fuzzy, flickering lines and all..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Horizontal lines flash randomly over laptop display](http://superuser.com/questions/773911/horizontal-lines-flash-randomly-over-laptop-display)

Answer (score 0):

Such a problem can be caused by an incorrect refresh rate or resolution.

Check your monitor specs. According to [newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824005112) :

```
Horizontal Refresh Rate  30 - 83kHz
Vertical Refresh Rate    56 - 75Hz 
Recommended Resolution   1680 x 1050
```

Check Windows Update for an optional update for your video card.

There also an LG software/firmware update for your model [here](http://www.lg.com/us/support/product/support-product-profile.jsp?customerModelCode=W2252TQ-TF&matchedModelCode=1000004019&searchEngineModelCode=W2252TQ-TF&initialTab=documents&targetPage=support-product-profile), but take good backups before trying it, since there is no documentation what exactly it does. If a firmware update fails, you could brick the monitor.

Comment: What would I backup before updating the monitor?

Comment: The best you can do is to have a way of reverting to the actual firmware. Better have a backup monitor, if this is your only one. Try to find more info on the LG support forums (if they exist). Be prepared for the worst!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried swapping the VGA cable with another one?  Or, better yet, upgrade to a DVI cable?

Sometimes the video resolution issues can be caused by a pinched wire in a VGA cable.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem, i found out that my Video Card was overheating due to a manufacturer fan problem. luckily it was under warranty and was fixed, hope i helped...

Answer (score 0):

### Change your Power Plan settings

The power plan is limiting the resources for the graphics card to function properly. Change all the settings to the Maximum Performance.

**How I fixed the problem:**

- Install the latest drivers from the official AMD website (Catalyst 14.0+).
- Change you Power Plan to High Performance (in battery and plugged-in).
- Go to Control Panel>Power Options>Change advanced power settings> ATI Graphics Power Settings> ATI Powerplay settings> On battery, Plugged in: **Maximum Performance**.
- Go to Control Panel>Power Options>Change advanced power settings> PCI Express> Link State Power Management> On battery, Plugged in: **Off**.
- Disable Aero (Choose the *Windows 7 Basic* theme)
- Restart your PC.

**Important:** This will also fix a constant change in the brightness level when you switch between dark and bright apps.